# Symfony 2 : How to prevent multiple user editing the same form at the same time?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

On my SF application, i have "regular" form (generated with formType in controller).

Let's say user1 edit the formA and it takes several minutes to fill it.
In that period, user2 also edit the formA.
You can guess, the last user that hit submit wins, and the other one looses all he filled.

How can i prevent this from happening? This is not the case of a multiple submit (by the same user).

I don't know if it's possible and how to best implement it, but my guess would be to add some "lock" mechanism.

I've read https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support

Would it suffice to add a @Version to a field in the entity for my Form and SF takes care of the rest ?

I would like that when user2 tries to open the form, i can send the message : *"Sorry, user1 is already completing the form"*. I don't want that user2 looses all he fills only when he hit submit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not provided out of the box by the framework.

What you can do is take advantage of the [Lock Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html) or implement a similar solution by yourself.

```
// Symfony\Component\Lock\Factory $factory

$lock = $factory->createLock('your-amazing-form-USER-ID');

if (!$lock->acquire()) {
    // Sorry, user1 is already completing the form
    // throw exception or render a template for example
}

// Do what you need to show the form.

// Form is submitted and valid? Do what you need and release the lock.
if ($form->submited()) {
    // Save to database
    $lock->release();
}
```

A good idea is to give a TTL to the lock so that if the user does not submits the form the lock is still released.
Since you still want that the user who acquired the lock is able to submit the form, then the resource name should contain for example the user identifier.

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. I'm afraid though such a mechanism is being nearly impossible to manage in my case where i have a form with many fields, where the TTL would then be impossible to be predicted because of the time it needs to be filled :( 
Otherwise, this component seems ok. 
The other bummer is i can't use it yet, since i'm still on SF 2.8. I'll have to upgrade all first to SF > 3.4 to be able to use it or as you say,

Comment: @Overdose you can still implement a similar solution by yourself, where you store for example on a database the locks done. Regarding the TTL you can put a sensible value, for example, will a user be 30 minutes filling a form? Or will be 1/2 minutes?

Comment: yes, that's what i thought about : a "dirty" entity with (user_id, form_entity_id, form_entity_type, time_form_opened) with a line inserted on form opened, the line would be deleted on form closed or after TTL. and i would check if a line exists when another user tries to edit and prevent it. I guess it covers the main stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can, clearly, use a lock so that only one user can access a form at a time, but as it is stated in a comment, you have to be careful your locks are released because otherwise no one can access the form until the user1 is finished.

This timeout mechanism is also a problem because if you set it too short, you will fall into the same problem, and if it is set too long, your users will be stuck.

You still could be setting a shorter lock, and put some client side script that warns the user when the lock is expired but this requires again more work.

On the other hand you could consider a mechanism where you allow all users to access the form, and where the first who submits has his data saved, and the later have a message telling him the data has been updated in between. This can be achieved, not by a `@Version` as you were looking for, but simply by adding an `update date` field.

With this field, you simply add this `update date` as a hidden field and when a user submits the form, you compare the value of the submitted field with the one on the entity and if the two values don't match, you warn the subsequent users about the fact the entity has been updated in between.