# How to generalize the mappping of a symfony entity that is potentially linked to many entities types

Tags: symfony

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428332/symfony-2-how-to-prevent-multiple-user-editing-the-same-form-at-the-same-time/52429744#52429744) i wanted to know how to prevent a user to edit a form if another user was already using it.
Since i'm using SF 2.8, i can't use the [lock component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html) (> SF3.4) so i was thinking about doing it manually, with an entity managing the locks.

for my entity, i need :

- user_id (the user that edit the form, create the lock)
- entity_id (the id of the edited entity)
- entity_class (FQCN of the entityType)
- createdAt (date of the lock)

moreover, i need a UniqueEntity constraint on (user_id, entity_id and entity_class)

This is where i have a problem of mapping : the entity (id) can be of different type (i have Profession, Module, Institution, User...)

So from a Doctrine point of view, i don"t see how i can do it.

maybe i can use the entity id, but loosing the very power of docrine/symfony relationships.

```
/**
 * Lockit.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="lockit")
 * 
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"entityClass", "entityId", "user"}
 * )
 */
class Lockit
{
  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * FQCN of the entity associated with the form to be locked.
   *
   * @var string
   * @ORM\Column(name="entity_class", type="string")
   */
  private $entityClass;

  /**
   * Entity id associated with the form to be locked.
   * @ORM\Column(name="entity_id", type="integer")
   */
  private $entityId;

  /**
   * @var \Simusante\SimustoryBundle\Entity\User
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Simusante\SimustoryUserBundle\Entity\User")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   * })
   */
  private $user;

  /**
   * Date of the lock creation.
   *
   * @var \DateTime
   * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
   * @Assert\Date()
   */
  private $createdAt;
```

Another solution would be to create as many lockEntities as i can lock entity with.
i would create a base Lock, and then a ProfessionLock, a InstitutionLock... where i could use the "correct" mapping.

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Institution")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institutionId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   * })
   */
  private $user;
```

it would work, but this doesn't feel as "optimized" as it could.

maybe there's another way to to it, where i don't have to create as many entities as i have form type to lock.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use `GUID`s for that, add a guid field to all your entities and then add a unique field of object's guid.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand : the guid (like the id of each entity for which i want to add a lock) is unique for one kind of entity, but a guid of entityA can be the same as guid of entityB... can you further explain what you mean. thanks

Comment: the purpose of guid/uuid is to be unique not only across one table (space) but it can guarantee uniqueness across space and time. You can read the  [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122)

Comment: ok, i see now. Indeed, with https://github.com/ramsey/uuid i think i could manage this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This is where i have a problem of mapping : the entity (id) can be of different type (i have Profession, Module, Institution, User...)

As I can see, just mapping the entityId field as a text field instead of integer should solve your issue.

Your UniqueEntity constraint would still be relevant, and you would still be able to recover any locked entity Lockit instance via a simple entity repository method or whatever query method you'd like.